# As user types, format text field with NSNumberFormatter extension in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter, uitextfielddelegate

I am working on a loan app, where I am struggling to figure out how to format the text fields as soon as the user types. It would be nice to see that because the outputs are calculated as soon as there is a digit in the textfield.

In my ViewController:

```
  @IBOutlet var loanTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet var interestTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet var interestStepper: UIStepper!
  @IBOutlet var termTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet var termStepper: UIStepper!
```

Created delegates to structure maximum lengths and allow decimals when it's applicable:

```
  var integerTextFieldDelegate = NumericTextFieldDelegate(maxLength: 2)
  var loanTextFieldDelegate = NumericTextFieldDelegate(maxLength: 10, allowDecimal: true)
  var interestRateTextFieldDelegate = NumericTextFieldDelegate(maxLength: 2, allowDecimal: true)
```

Delegates are defined for each text fields in viewDidLoad:

```
loanTextField.text = ""
loanTextField.delegate = loanTextFieldDelegate

interestRateTextField.setTextNumericValue(DefaultInterestRate)
interestRateTextField.delegate = interestRateTextFieldDelegate

termTextField.setTextNumericValue(DefaultTerm)
termTextField.delegate = interestRateTextFieldDelegate
```

NumericTextFieldDelegate are referred to an extension:

```
// Implementation of UITextFieldDelegate that prevents non-numeric characters
// from being entered in a numeric text field.
public class NumericTextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
  let maxLength: Int
  let allowDecimal: Bool

  public init(maxLength: Int, allowDecimal: Bool = false) {
    self.maxLength = maxLength
    self.allowDecimal = allowDecimal
  }

  public func textField(textField: UITextField!,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String!) -> Bool
  {
    let originalText: NSString = textField.text
    let proposedText: NSString = originalText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    let proposedLength = proposedText.length
    if proposedLength > maxLength {
      return false
    }

    if allowDecimal {
      if proposedLength > 0 && !isValidDoubleString(proposedText) {
        return false
      }
    }
    else {
      if proposedLength > 0 && !isValidIntegerString(proposedText) {
        return false
      }
    }

    return true
  }
}
```

I also have a number formatter extension:

```
public extension Double {
  var formatted: String {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator?
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    return formatter.stringFromNumber(self)!
  }
}
```

My question due to my lack of experience. How do I format the text field for loan ($ currency, 2 decimals and grouping separator) and interest rate (3 decimals at all times since it's in the increment of 1/8th) using my extensions. I seen other shouldChangeCharactersInRange method or having some blank UILabel to display the formatted text...but I'm unsure how to do it in Swift given my current set up. Thanks for any helpful tip!!

Answer (score 0):

I was making a calculator app where in the display I wanted to format the number as user typing in with `NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle`, so my code was like this when the user presses <kbd>1</kbd>:

```
var addOne:Character = "1"
userInput.text.append(addOne)
var formatNumber:NSNumber = userInput.text.toInt()!

var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
var formattedNumber = formatter.stringFromNumber(formatNumber)!

userInput.text = "\(formattedNumber)"
```

But it didn't quite work because after formatting a number like `1,111` it gives me an error.

Now I understand the error that formattedNumber is not a number anymore so it gives nil value. To fix that I wrote this code:

```
var addOne:Character = "1"
userInput.text.append(addOne)

var getString:NSString = input.text
var newString = getString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "")

var formatNumber:NSNumber = newString.toInt()!

var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
var formattedNumber = formatter.stringFromNumber(formatNumber)!

userInput.text = "\(formattedNumber)"
```

It removes `,`s for the NSNumber, and NSNumber stays a number which can be formatted as many times you want.

and You can setup maximum number to you textField like this:

formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 12

it will work since you are displaying a formatted number